# Read Amazon Shopping Cart

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am Developing an application(on Mobile) and one of the features needs to read the shopping cart a user has made on amazon.

1. The user opens amazon from any browser
2. the user opens my app
3. logins with amazon user and pass
4. after that i need the app to read the card and only display the items

is this possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Hmmm. So you want people to log in to your app with their amazon username and password?

Comment: i dont know if i can use amazon webservices for login like Facebook ,thats why iam just asking

Comment: Sounds like your first port of call is the documentation, to discover what is possible with the api.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the amazon product advertising API. Be sure to read the full documentation.

The API has many methods that can be used to search, look up created and modify shopping cart.

**Link:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html